# NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 400 for https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions in Volley

Tags: java, android, http

I have faced a err when I am using Volley POST method. I have tried using HTTP Connection There is works, But I am wanting call the api using volley

my code is:

```
String apiUrl = "https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions";
        String apiToken = "r8_Ya8ZvjER5IjbmqnFeq2iNJqdqtqc24t1HFo3X";

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        StringRequest objectRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, apiUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                System.out.println(response);
                Toast.makeText(context, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                System.out.println(error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(context, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            }
        }) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("version", "494ca4d578293b4b93945115601b6a38190519da18467556ca223d219c3af9f9");
                map.put("input", String.valueOf(new HashMap<String, String>(){{
                    put("model", "Image Denoising");
                    put("image", image);

                }}));
                System.out.println(map);
                return map;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>(super.getHeaders());
                headers.put("Authorization","Token "+ apiToken);
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                return headers;
            }
        };

        queue.add(objectRequest);
```

This is the HTTP code which they provide in there Documentation:

```
curl -s -X POST \
  -d '{"version": "494ca4d578293b4b93945115601b6a38190519da18467556ca223d219c3af9f9", "input": {"model": "Image Denoising", "image": "(image url)"}}' \
  -H "Authorization: Token $REPLICATE_API_TOKEN" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  "https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions" | jq
```

I have try that code which I give up. But it show,

```
NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 400 for https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions
```

What I can do now, How to solve this?